# JQuery UI sortable does not efficently sort big images?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been using JQUery UI sortbale where there are images in a sortable list. When the list gets longer, the efficeincy of sorting gets slower. Sometimes the placeholder doesnt show up at the place where I intend to drop it, or just takes too long to appear.

I m not aware that is it a performance bug or there is something which I may have not looked at.

I searched stackoverflow for a solution but I found the solutions for sortable performance issues when they are connected to other sortables. I could find solutions regarding performance issues for self-sorting big images.

Here is my basic code.

```
$(function() {
      $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
           placeholder: "marker",
           axis: "y",
           opacity: 0.1,
           scrollSpeed: 100
      });
});

<ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8050/8384821879_4a38e7b49c.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8233/8383743110_1d54957f9d.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8515/8383743936_436f8a683c.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8237/8367576814_f70d6c92e6.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8042/7984956055_ea5992fd01.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8045/8385132987_07a624ff4d.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8386232790_837708cc32.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8192/8385130425_b0706a57cd.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8048/8379388943_9c84fab1ec.jpg"/></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8092/8386229678_14b72aac69.jpg"/></li>
      </ul>
```

Working demo fiddle to illustrate the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/CJ9tN/1/

Comment: that is appearing at the top.

Comment: sorry, didnt understand you

Comment: i mean if you click the image to drag you can see a place holder at the top of the images. just drag and drop it there.

Comment: Yes, but try to drag the top image to the bottom. While dragging, you can observe that the placeholder doesnt pop up between some images, or takes a while to show up